# mockk verify lambda argument

Tags: kotlin, mockk

I'd like to verify the value which was passed in via a lamdba.
The func looks like this:

```
fun save(entity: Any, idSupplier: () -> UUID): JsonEntity {
    return save(JsonEntity(idSupplier(), entity, entity::class.simpleName!!))
}
```

Now within my test I'd like to verify the value which has been passed in for the `idSupplier`. I made a mock to return a value for the `save(...)` which is called in my own `save(..., () -> ...)` like this

```
every { jsonStorage.save(any<JsonEntity>()) } answers { value }
```

Now on `verify` I have this now

```
verify(exactly = 1) { jsonStorage.save(event, any()) }
```

Which is working, but I'd like to know the exact value which has been passed, i.e. if the entity's id was 123, I'd like to verify this.

Thank you in advance

Comment: See also [How to run lambda function passed to a mockked method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61108797/how-to-run-lambda-function-passed-to-a-mockked-method)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need a Slot for [capturing the parameters](https://mockk.io/#capturing).

**Example**

```
val id = slot<UUID>()
every { save(any<JsonEntity>()) { capture(id)} } answers { value }

// `id.captured` contains the value passed 
// as a parameter in the lambda expression `idSupplier`

assertEquals(UUID.fromString("4195f789-2730-4f99-8b10-e5b9562210c1"), id.captured)
```

Comment: Thnx for this answer, this helps me forward.  
What about the verify-part?
Does that remain the same, or can I be more specific inside the verify?

Comment: @TomdeVroomen, sure, you can use `id.captured` to verify its value

Comment: @TomdeVroomen I updated my answer to show how to use the `Slot`

Comment: Thanks for the solution, that brought me on the right track. However, the example didn't quite meet my situation because I wanted to capture the lambda itself. Over on Medium there is a [great article](https://medium.com/@marco_cattaneo/kotlin-unit-testing-with-mockk-91d52aea2852) that does exactly that: `val captureCallback = slot<() -> UUID>(); every { save(capture(captureCallback)) } answers { ... }`

Comment: @J.Buehler I have never used this function before, but it seems to me that for capturing lambda you can use `captureLambda()` function https://mockk.io/