# How to run lambda function passed to a mockked method?

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, functional-programming, mockk

I wonder whather it's possible to run a lambda function passed as a parameter to a mocked function. And run it whenever the mocked method is called.

I am using Mockk and I imagine the code to be something like this:

```
class DataManager {
   fun submit(lambda: (Int) => Unit) { ... }
}

...

val mock = mockk<DataManager>()

every { mock.submit(lambda = any()) }.run { lambda(5) }
```

In my real implementation the datamanager calls a server and runs the lambda as a callback when it recieves a successful response. The lambda happens to be a private method of the class under test.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use a Capture instead of Any.

```
val dataManager: DataManager = mockk()

every { dataManager.submit(captureLambda()) } answers { lambda<(Int) -> Unit>().invoke(5) }

dataManager.submit { i -> println(i) }
```

Additionally the the declaration of your function type is invalid.

You have `(Int) => Unit` when it should be `(Int) -> Unit`.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer, helped me a lot. But there is a small bug. It should actually be `every { mock.submit(lambda = capture(slot) ) } `. The `capture` is missing in your answer. It would be great if you coud update it :)

Comment: Glad to help. I was guessing at the syntax last night and decided to double check this afternoon. I found out that mockk has specific matchers and answer scope extensions for this scenario. I've updated accordingly.

Answer (score 7):

Can be solve in the following ways.

with args from answer:

```
every { dataManager.submit(any()) } answers {
      firstArg<(Int) -> Unit>().invoke(5)
}
```

or with captureLambda

```
every { dataManager.submit(captureLambda()) } answers {
      lambda<(Int) -> Unit>().captured.invoke(5)
}
```